# Unable to find assembly Entity Framework v 4.4.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, excel, entity-framework

We're on `VS2010` and have Entity Framework working for a number of things. The reference is there, it's 4.4.0.0. There are SO threads with the same error saying it can be a mismatch due to .net versions, however since EF calls work in parts of the program, that seems unlikely. I've uninstalled and reinstalled EF a few times, and no luck there.

This error happens on the `SaveChanges()` :

> Unable to find assembly Entity Framework 4.4.0.0

```
   // add to permissions table
   EAT_Permissions permission = new EAT_Permissions
   {
         action_id = actionID,
         login = userLogin
   };
   context.EAT_Permissions.Attach(permission);
   context.EAT_Permissions.Add(permission);
   context.SaveChanges();
   permissionsDGV.Refresh();
   MessageBox.Show("Permission was added");
```

[image]

In comparison, working code:

```
if (context.EAT_Users.Any(p => p.login == userLogin))
            {   
                var removeUser = context.EAT_Users.Find(userLogin);
                context.EAT_Users.Attach(removeUser);
                context.EAT_Users.Remove(removeUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
                userListDGV.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("User was removed");
            }
            else..
```

Comment: as a sanity check, is the EntityFramework.dll file in the bin folder? have you checked the .csproj file to make sure the correct reference is there? have you cleaned and rebuilt the solution? have you checked the entity framework reference in the app.config/web.config (whichever applies) file?

Comment: Yep, yep and yep. :( It works fine for a number of other calls, so I'm thinking it's due to how the table is laid out... but it'd be a strange error for that. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @user1666620 if you have multiple projects that are in charge of your DAL, it could be that there's a mismatch between those project, or there could be a bindingRedirect for EF version in one of the config files.

Comment: does your solution contain multiple projects? are they referencing different versions of entity framework?

Comment: @Default Only one project in my solution. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Check the properties of the EF dll in the output folder. Is it the correct version?

Comment: @Basic File version for EF.dll is 4.4.20627.0 ... references to EF in the rest of the app are 4.4.0.0. Think that could have an impact?

Comment: Possible... Depends on how the reference to the Dll is configured in your .config file/project. It's not uncommon for references to specify a range of supported versions. Assuming you can roll this change back easily (eg using source control)... Copy the EF Dll from the output folder somewhere outside the build tree. Remove all references to EF, add a reference to the copied Dll. Depending on whether it works, fails at compile time or fails at runtime will tell us more.

Comment: @Basic Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it and unfortunately the same runtime error pops up.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was on the wrong track then. That new Dll reference should be for the correct version. Can you post some working code to compare/contrast?

Comment: added working code in op

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72240/discussion-between-basic-and-spacesteak).

Comment: What is the stack trace of the "Unable to find assembly Entity Framework 4.4.0.0" exception?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer, but here are some *sanity* checks and questions which may lead you to the answer.

1. Has the edmx file been updated to the latest database?
2. Can you create a scratch project, get it up and running and do the process? Does the same happen? What can be gleamed from the working project...version numbers etc.
3. Is this request in a WPF program, an web service, Silverlight?
4. Does the user or login being used have permissions to save to the database?
5. Can you move the version to EF 5 (which works in VS2010 and minimum .Net 4)?